# How would you plot an results ion iterations of nested for loops?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a nested for loop and can't seem to plot all of my results at the same time.

In print 1, I can see all of the results I want to plot, however, if I try to move my plot commands to this indentation, I get 5 separate graphs (I only want 1).

The current plot commands only give me the last 'set' of data.

I have tried adding extra

```
array_1 = np.append(array_1, [a,x])
```

statements at the other indentation levels to try to append all of these 'sets', but then I only seem to get one plot point.

```
for j in range (5):    

    x = 0.1         
    a = 0.2                         
    array_1 = np.array([a, x])    

    for i in range(10):   

        x = x**2                        
        array_1 = np.append(array_1, [a,x])    
        array_1 = array_1.reshape(-1,2)

    # print 1 gives all 55 the points I want to plot 
    print(j, i, array_1)

# print 2 only gives the last 11 points
#print(j, i, array_1)

plt.plot(array_1[:,0], array_1[:,1],'r.')     
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you do `array_1 = np.array([a, x])` near the beginning of the outer loop you are resetting it, so you are throwing away everything you appended in previous iterations. What you could do is replace this with an `append` similar to the one you use inside the inner loop and add at the very beginning `array_1 = np.array([])`. But what you really should do is not use loops at all here.

Comment: this still doesn't work... :(

Comment: What is your expected output? As it is, all the `j` loop does is repeat the exact same calculation 5 times

Comment: Hi, sorry, I figured it out. I had a few nested loops and just had to move it outside all of them. oops. but thanks x